# What armor and weapons do Crusaders use?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

Every class in Diablo 3 has its own specialized weapons and armor. Some of those are really unique, like the quiver or voodoo doll, while others look almost the same as every other piece of armor, such as the Barbarian belt or the Demonhunter cape. The one thing in common is that each of these weapons or armor pieces can only be used by the respective class.

Now I've seen 'flails' in the Live version of the game that say they can only be used by Crusaders, but are there any other items? Also, which items found in the current game were Crusader-only in the beta?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Reaper of Souls isn't out yet. So except for the limited group of choosen beta testers this would be impossible to know.

Comment: yeah but the data is already in the game (or at least a part of it)  otherwise i can't explain why I found a flail. Maybe someone else found some other Items.

Comment: [This page lists pretty much everything known about crusaders right now](http://www.diablowiki.net/Crusader). You can see there that the crusader specific weapons and armor are flails and crusader shields.

Comment: We come down rather hard on questions about unreleased games, due to our inability to actually answer them.  What you *could* do, if you want to get this reopened, is to focus on what the purpose of these Crusader-only items you found are for, since the Crusader isn't actually playable.  There might be a valid question there.

Comment: You can't focus on both the unreleased game, and the beta.  You have to pick one or the other.  The entire question has to focus on the dropped items, such as, "I found this flail, what is it good for?".  Just going, "Hey, I found this flail, what other Crusader weapons are there?" is still off-topic, because it hasn't been released.

Comment: @Frank There [was a non-NDA closed beta with opt-in from all D3 owners](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/11954350/reaper-of-souls%E2%84%A2-closed-beta-now-available-12-12-2013), which included the content mentioned here. This makes the question, by our standards, on topic.

Comment: @FEichinger Except the question is referring to both the unreleased game, AND the beta.  It doesn't work both ways.  If he wants to limit it to specifically the beta, I have no problems with it.  If he's referring to the unreleased game, I'm slapping another close vote on it the instant it gets reopened.

Comment: @Frank Nonsense. It's not "referring to the unreleased game and the beta". It's asking about content that was included in the beta and is slated for release in the near future. We *never* required that questions "refer only to the beta" for content that just isn't literally *released* yet.

Comment: (Don't get me wrong, that last edit caused some issues with the question and I'd gladly retract my reopen vote if that didn't cause other problems. But "it's off-topic because unreleased" is incorrect, plain and simple.)

Comment: @FEichinger I don't care how you interpret it.  I've given my advice, and why I feel it's off-topic.  I feel very much that unreleased = off-topic.  We deal with *playable* stuff.  Beta was playable.  Unreleased game is not.  Therefore, if he's referring to the game *that's not out yet*, I can and *will* vote to close it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not much(or pretty much nothing) is known about *Crusaders*, there is a bit of info on the net. What I found [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Crusader)(even tho' I realize it's not a 100% trustworthy source) is:

> Class-Specific Items
>
> - Flails
> - Crusader Shields

There is no other info that I could find about class-specific *Crusader* items yet.

Comment: What do you mean there is not much known? The beta has been out for almost half a year and there never was an NDA. Crusaders have been played for thousands of hours by streamers already. I'm not sure if all that info was documented somewhere, but I find it hard to believe no one wrote down the crusader specific weapons and armor somewhere. brb, going to find it :)

Comment: Actually, it has been very hard to find information specifically about the Crusader. The official Crusader skill calculator popped up recently on battle.net. Even before that, it was nearly impossible to find updated skills/runes for the Crusader. Many sites had information from mid to late 2012.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Items section of the official Game Guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/#filter=crusader), crusader class-specific items include **one-handed flails, two-handed flails, and crusader shields**.  See those items marked with 'Cru'.

The Game Guide also shows that, including items specific to other classes, crusaders *can't use* staves or any ranged weapon.

Answer (score 1):

Crusaders use maces, flails and shields. you can also equip a 2h weapon in 1 hand with a passive skill (although not dual wielding, crusaders always must wear a shield)

Comment: i don't undertsnad why my answer got downvvoted as it's the right information

Comment: provide a source

Comment: source:http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/13354137/crusader-skill-design-qa-18-03-2014

Comment: It seems this answer is indeed accurate. I provided my upvote.

Comment: but i don't think you HAVE to wear a shield. But there's no reason for you to ever not do it.

Comment: And this answer is *exactly* why we don't allow questions about games not released yet.

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoters, but looking at the source only indicates that Flails are the class weapon.  It does not indicate anything about Maces except that Crusaders can use them (is there any class that can't use a 2-handed mace?).  It also indicates that they can use Daggers.  The bit about using a 2-hander with a shield is non-responsive to this question (although it is correct).  The other answer is clearly superior in answering the question asked.  This answer is misleading (suggesting that there is something special about Crusaders and Maces).